# How to compare first element of a column with other elements in CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I want to compare first element of a column with other elements of same column and next column and print element which is present once only in both the columns as well as value in its corresponding column. For eg:

> Col1   Col2
>   111    243
>   111    145
>       213    111
>       289    200
>   222    213

In this example 243 is present only once but 111(value in corresponding column) is present more then once. I want to print only

> 289    200

My code is:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass
f = open("1.csv", 'r')
reader = csv.reader(f)
a = []
b = []
c = []
for row in reader:
    a.append(row[0])
    b.append(row[1])
val = [i for i,j in OrderedCounter(a).items() if j==1]
val1 = [i for i,j in OrderedCounter(b).items() if j==1]
```

It is giving me the unique values of each column

Comment: So to be clear, when checking if 289 is to be kept, you check that 289 is not present elsewhere in col1, then check that 200 is not present in col1 either? I.e., you are verifying that each of the elements in a given row is unique to its respective column?

Comment: I you had another row that was `200  213`, that would not affect your decision to retain `289  200` because the 200 would be in col1 this time, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter    
import csv

values = Counter()
data = {}

with open('1.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)    # comment out if no actual header

    for row in csv_input:
        values[row[0]] += 1
        values[row[1]] += 1
        data[row[0]] = row[1]

for value, count in values.items():
    try:
        if count == 1 and values[data[value]] == 1:
            print '{} {}'.format(value, data[value])
    except KeyError as e:
        pass
```

This would display:

```
289  200
```